# Measures of dependence for the pair (X, Y)

Tags: correlation, joint-distribution

If for a set of two bivariate random variables, $(X,Y_{1})$ and $(X,Y_{2})$, we know that

- marginal cdf of $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are the same and
- $E(Y_{2}|X>x)\geq E(Y_{1}|X>x)$ for all $x$,

then we say that $Y_{2}$ is more correlated with X than $Y_{1}$.

In the special case of the normal distribution, where both $(X,Y_{1})$ and $(X,Y_{2})$ are joint normally distributed, this definition boils down to the usual (Pearson) correlation.

This sounds to me a well-defined definition, and I am wondering whether it is related to other correlation definitions, I checked many, e.g. correlation order, spearman, Kendall with no success.

Comment: That is not possible. By the law of iterated expectations $E[Y_2] > E[Y_1]$ (or set $x$ to $-\infty$)

Comment: It is possible, consider the case of bivariate normal distribution. In that case, this boils down to the usual correlation coefficient. I am not trying to invent things for the sake of it, rather it is an application-driven question.

Comment: I have just proven to you it's not possible. Look up the law of iterated expectations... Also, your set-up contains 3 random variables, so word "bivariate" does not capture the situation.

Comment: Please note that it is "larger or equal" so in the limit case, they are always equal as you pointed out.

Comment: Well, now you've changed it: from "$>$" to "$\geq$". Now the inequality does not mean much. Now it is possible that $Y_1 = Y_2$.

Comment: You are right and that is fine, the same is true when we define correlation order.

Comment: It is possible for $Corr(X,Y_2) > Corr(X,Y_1)$. It is not possible to have "$>$" in your inequality, as I have stated twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118981/discussion-between-anon-and-stans).

Comment: Although this definition makes mathematical sense, it isn't related to the concept of correlation, nor does it appear useful. As pointed out by @stans, *if $Y_1$ has a defined expectation* then your criterion implies $Y_1=Y_2$ (almost surely). Otherwise it is possible for $X$ to have a negative relationship with $Y_2$ and a positive relationship with $Y_1.$  Example: Let $X$ have a uniform distribution on the interval $[-1,1],$ let $Y$ have a Cauchy distribution, and set $Y_i=X+(3-2i)Y.$

Comment: Thanks whuber. In your example, do Y1 and y2 have the same marginal cdf? I am not sure.

Comment: By symmetry, the $Y_i$ must have identical distributions.

Comment: You are right but in your example, $Y_{2}$ is more correlated with $X$ than $Y_{1}$, and vice-versa, in a way they are as correlated as each other with $X$, that is fine, no? I see that this does not fit with Pearson correlation etc but that is exactly my question, is there other measure of dependence(correlation) that are related to the one above?

Comment: To avoid such cases, we can change the deinifion by having $E(Y_{2}|X>x)\geq E(Y_{1}|X>x)$ for all $x$ and with strict inequality in for some $x$, instead